# Basic Question about If and If else implementation

Tags: c, if-statement

I am trying to understand why if else is needed for this kind of implementation

Here is my working code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int Num, row, columns; //Let Num = User Input 
    
    printf("ﾟ｡✧ʕっ•ᴥ•ʔっ PLease Enter a Number from 4 and 50 ⊂ʕ •ᴥ•⊂ ʔﾟ｡✧: \n");
    scanf("%d", &Num);
    
    char arr[Num][Num];
    
    if (Num >= 4 && Num <= 50){
        for (int row=0; row<Num; row++)
        {
            for (int columns=0; columns<Num; columns++){
                if (row == 0 || columns == 0){
                    arr[row][columns]='*';
                }
                else if (row == Num-1 || columns == Num-1){
                    arr[row][columns]='*'; 
                }
                else
                    arr[row][columns] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    else 
        printf("Error! Please enter a valid number :)");

    for(int i = 0; i < Num; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < Num; j++ ){
            printf("%c", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is (depending on inputed `Num`)

```
4
****
*  *
*  *
****
```

My question is why does the code not work if I don't use `if else` here

```
for (int columns=0; columns<Num; columns++){
                if (row == 0 || columns == 0){
                    arr[row][columns]='*';
                }
                if (row == Num-1 || columns ==Num-1){
                    arr[row][columns]='*'; 
                }
                else
                    arr[row][columns] = ' ';
            }
```

The output will be like this

```
4
   *
   *
   *
****
```

I know that `if-else` statements are executed if the first `if` is false and won't execute `if` is true.

Thank you for any responses in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we reformat the original:

```
if (row == 0 || columns == 0){
    arr[row][columns]='*';
}
else if (row == Num-1 || columns ==Num-1){
    arr[row][columns]='*'; 
}
else
    arr[row][columns] = ' ';
```

Into

```
if (row == 0 || columns == 0){
    arr[row][columns]='*';
}
else{
    if (row == Num-1 || columns ==Num-1){
        arr[row][columns]='*'; 
    }
    else{
        arr[row][columns] = ' ';
    }
}
```

Then you can clearly see that the difference. Especially considering the stand-alone `else` part.

With this, if `row == 0 || columns == 0` is false then nothing is executed. But without the `else if` the stand-alone `else` part will happen for `row == 0` and `column == 0`, overwriting what you set earlier.

Comment: Thank you for the response! you are right, the logical flow of the code is clearer when written in that format!

Answer (score 1):

In the original code, `else` statement executes only when both conditions `row == 0 || columns == 0` and `row == Num-1 || columns ==Num-1` are false.

In the updated code, `else` is executed when `row == Num-1 || columns ==Num-1` is false.

If `row == 0 || columns == 0` is true, both first if block and else statement are executed, and `'*'` is written to the array, but then it is overwritten with `' '`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Follow up question, so if there are multiple consecutive `if` statements and no `else if` then the final `else` will only execute if the last `if` statement is false and disregarding the previous `if` statements?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1):

`if` statements check for all multiple available `if` . while else if check when `if` statements fails , `if` statement return true it will not check for `else if`.

so it is depend on scenario how your requirement is.

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't work because the last else *will* be executed **for all** occurrences where row != 3 and col != 3. This will in effect overwrite the first row and column of stars. `if-else` is needed to *exclude* those occurrences from happening.

You can see the original, correct code as:

```
if (row == 0 || columns == 0) {
    arr[row][columns]='*';
}
else
{
    if (row == Num-1 || columns == Num-1) {
        arr[row][columns]='*'; 
    }
    else
        arr[row][columns] = ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because in case if you remove the `else` from the second `else if`, the second and third condition will form the `if-else` pair.

For example,
let row = 0, col = 0, Num = 4 :

It will satisfy the first condition `if (row == 0 || columns == 0)` and set the value `arr[row][col] = arr[0][0] = '*';`

But then it will encounter second condition `(row == Num-1 || columns == Num-1)` which returns **False** as row = col = 0 and Num-1 = 3.

So it will go to its `else` part where

`arr[0][0] = ' '`  will become null character again.

Basically, your program will behave as :

```
    if {
        ....
    }

   { 
     if {
        ....
     }
     else {
      ...
     }
   }
```

Hope this explanation helps you :)